# tor profile missing or inaccessible

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, linux

I recently reset the settings on my tor browser, and now when i try to open it i get a window with the following message:

> Your Tor Browser profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible.

I am using Linux mint 17.3 KDE. I have tried uninstalling Tor, and then installing it again, but the same issue keeps happening.

Comment: What do you mean by "uninstalling Tor"? What exactly did you do?